# Dúvida no debug de merge sort com Javascript

Tags: javascript, classificação, recursão, debug

Estou estudando estruturas de dados com Javascript e até agora tava tudo ok. Só que quando eu cheguei nos algoritmos de ordenação, mais especificamente no merge sort, eu acabei travando, não consigo entender a ordem de execução que ele segue. Há uma dupla recursão, enfim, tá bem confuso pra mim. Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço muito. Segue o código:

```
var mergeSortRec = function(array) {
    var length = array.length
    if(length === 1) {
        return array
    }
    var mid = Math.floor(length / 2),
    left = array.slice(0, mid),
    right = array.slice(mid, length)
    return merge(mergeSortRec(left), mergeSortRec(right))
}

var merge = function(left, right) {
    var result = [],
    il = 0,
    ir = 0

    while(il < left.length && ir < right.length) {
        if(left[il] < right[ir]) {
            result.push(left[il++])
        } else {
            result.push(right[ir++])
        }
    }

    while(il < left.length) {
        result.push(left[il++])
    }

    while(ir < right.length) {
        result.push(right[ir++])
    }

    return result
}
```

Suponha que o array inserido seja esse: `[6,2,5,2,4,5]`

Comment: Confuso é amplo demais, pode dar mais detalhes da sua dificuldade?